# How to check which Codeigniter like query return data in multiple like

Tags: php, codeigniter

I try to find out How to check which like query return data. users can search as 1. Location 2. vendors name, 3. category name. assume user search India where India can also a vendor name. Now query return some results as a location and some other as a vendor name. I want to store location matching results into location array and 
vendor name matching results into vendor_name array and then return both arrays.

**Here is My Model**

```
<?php 
    class Search_M extends CI_Model{
        public function getSearchResults($search_query){
            $this->db->select('ov_activity.activity_id,ov_activity.timing,vendor_name,vendor_img,address');
            $this->db->from('ov_activity');
            $this->db->join('ov_vendors', 'ov_activity.vendor_id = ov_vendors.vendor_id','left');
            $this->db->join('ov_category', 'ov_activity.category_id = ov_category.category_id','left');
            $this->db->like('ov_vendors.vendor_name', $search_query);
            $this->db->or_like('ov_vendors.address', $search_query);
            $this->db->or_like('category_name', $search_query);

            $query  =   $this->db->get();
            return $query->result();
        }
    }
?>
```

**Here is my controller**

```
<?php
    public function search_post() {
        $is_valid_token  = $this->authorization_token->validateToken();

        if(!empty($is_valid_token) AND $is_valid_token['status'] === TRUE)
        {
            $searchData = array();
            $searchData['query'] = $this->post('query');

            $getSearchResults = $this->Search_M->getSearchResults($searchData['query']);
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($getSearchResults);
            exit;
    }
?>
```

Comment: just print query.

Comment: @DevsiOdedra If I print query in my model it returns CI_DB_mysqli_result Object

Comment: use echo $this->db->last_query();

Comment: @DevsiOdedra it returns SELECT `ov_activity`.`activity_id`, `ov_activity`.`timing`, `vendor_name`, `vendor_img`, `address`
FROM `ov_activity`
LEFT JOIN `ov_vendors` ON `ov_activity`.`vendor_id` = `ov_vendors`.`vendor_id`
LEFT JOIN `ov_category` ON `ov_activity`.`category_id` = `ov_category`.`category_id`
WHERE  ov_vendors.vendor_name  LIKE '%fit n fine%' ESCAPE '!' 
OR  ov_vendors.address  LIKE '%fit n fine%' ESCAPE '!' 
OR  category_name  LIKE '%fit n fine%' ESCAPE '!'

Comment: @DevsiOdedra I have try everything that i know. Now I have no idea what I do. Please Help

Comment: you can check with search key and db column to check for which it matches. eg. if location column matches $searck key then it belong to location search and next matches with address column then that is for address search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Below logic,

```
  function filter_record($result,$searchKeyword) {
     $setArr = array(); 
     $setArr['Location'] =  array();
     $setArr['Cat'] = array(); 
     $setArr['Vendor'] = array(); 

    foreach($result as $row) {
        if (stristr($row->location_field, $searchKeyword) ) {
                $setArr['Location'][] = $row;
        }else if (stristr($row->cat_field, $searchKeyword) ) {
                $setArr['Cat'][] = $row;
        }else if (stristr($row->vendor_field, $searchKeyword) ) {
                $setArr['Vendor'][] = $row;
        }


    }
    return   $setArr;
}
```

Comment: $result is a database result which you gets using $query->result()

Comment: It gives an error strpos(): needle is not a string or an integer

Comment: print_r($result)
<pre>Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [activity_id] => 2
            [timing] => 5:00AM - 8:00AM
            [vendor_name] =>  FIT N FINE GYM
            [vendor_img] => User_icon_BLACK-0115.png
            [address] => 61/214, RAJAT PATH, MANSAROVAR, JAIPUR
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [activity_id] => 3
            [timing] => 
            [vendor_name] =>  FIT N FINE GYM
            [vendor_img] => User_icon_BLACK-0115.png
            [address] => 61/214, RAJAT PATH, MANSAROVAR, JAIPUR
        )

Comment: have you changed $row->location_field with your field name?

Comment: Yes sir I change field names

Comment: Have you passed $searchKeyword ?

Comment: Yes I passed $searchKeyword. and also I getting data in foreach If I print $row

Comment: Code updated please check. Let me know it will work for you or not.

Comment: Thank you very much sir Now everything is working like a charm